# Dynamic UI on Button click, changing DIV id dynamically

Tags: javascript, html

I have an UI, which adds fields based on button click. Looks like below [image: UI]

Each click on add entry, would add a div row as shown. However, when I delete something in between, the need of the task is to have a continous representation of IDs( Eg: We have opt-row.0, opt-row.1,opt-row.2. But if I delete the middle entry, I have opt-row0 and opt-row2. )[image: UI2]

Again pressing add entry, would create ambiguos rows( opt-row2), because i have decremented the count while deleting.

What I would like to have is, every time I delete, if there is something beyond that ID, I want it to reduce to one less( opt-row.2 becomes opt-row.1) So that I have continuity?

[image: UI3]

Could you give me some insights on how this can be achieved?

Script:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>

    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Include Bootstrap 5 -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </link>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <!-- Include https://datatables.net/ -->
    <link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </link>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript"
        src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.5/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- drag select for list of worklogs -->
    <style>
        .noselect {
            user-select: none;
        }

        .ds-selected {
            outline: 1px solid black;
            outline-offset: 0px;
            color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
            font-weight: bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div th:fragment="inputdata">
        <div class="container-md">
            <a>Student and Project Details</a>
            <div class="row justify-content-md-end">
                <form>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a>Enter unique studentId</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="studentid" id="studentid"
                                placeholder="studentid" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a>Enter Name</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="name"
                                required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a>birth date</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="date" class="form-control" name="birthdate" id="birthdate"
                                placeholder="birthdate" required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-2">
                            <a>Offer sum</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-3">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="sum" id="sum" placeholder="sum">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row-2">
                            <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sml" id="addingEntry" value="Add Entry">
                        </div>
                    </div>



                    <div id="form-placeholder"></div>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <br>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row-2">
                            <input type="submit" id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary btn-sml" value="Enter to DB">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script>
            function performCalculations() {
                var constantprice = document.getElementById("staticinput");
                var input = document.getElementById("checkinginput");
                var value = input.value;
                document.getElementById("result").value = value * constantprice.value;
            }


            function appendUserRow(id) {
                var html = "<div id=\"opt-row." + id + "\" class=\"form-group row\">\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-1\">\n" +
                    "                <input required type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"opt-type." + id + "\" name=\"opt-type." + id + "\" placeholder=\"ID\" >\n" +
                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-2\">\n" +
                    "                <input required type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"opt-name." + id + "\" name=\"opt-name." + id + "\" placeholder=\"Name\" >\n" +
                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-2\">\n" +
                    "                <input required type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" oninput =\"performCalculations(" + id + ")\" id=\"opt-price_per_piece." + id + "\" name=\"Price per piece." + id + "\" placeholder=\"Price per piece\">\n" +
                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-2\">\n" +
                    "                <input required type=\"number\" class=\"form-control\" oninput =\"performCalculations(" + id + ")\" id=\"opt-quantity." + id + "\" name=\"Quantity." + id + "\" placeholder=\"Quantity\">\n" +
                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-2\">\n" +
                    "                <input required type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" id=\"opt-sum." + id + "\" name=\"Quantity." + id + "\" placeholder=\"Sum\" >\n" +
                    "            </div>\n" +
                    "            <div class=\"col-1\">\n" +
                    "                <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"delRow(" + id + ")\" class=\"btn btn-danger\">Delete</button>\n" +
                    "           </div>\n" +
                    "            <div>\n" +
                    "                <br>\n" +
                    "           </div>\n" +
                    "        </div>";
  
                $("#form-placeholder").append(html);
            }
            var count = 0;
            function delRow(id) {
                var element = document.getElementById("opt-row." + id);
                var sumValue = document.getElementById("sum");
                var perPiece = document.getElementById("opt-price_per_piece." + id);
                var quantity = document.getElementById("opt-quantity." + id);
                if(document.getElementById("opt-row."+ id+1)){
                    console.log("We have entries in the next div");
                }
                var multipliedValue = perPiece.value * quantity.value;
                sumValue.value = sumValue.value - multipliedValue;
                element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                count--;
            }

            function performCalculations(id) {
                var sumValue = document.getElementById("sum");
                var perPiece = document.getElementById("opt-price_per_piece." + id);
                var quantity = document.getElementById("opt-quantity." + id);
                var multipliedValue = perPiece.value * quantity.value;
                
                var sumMultipliedValue = 0;
                if(id>0){
                    for(let i =0; i<id;i++){
                        var valuePerPiece =  document.getElementById("opt-price_per_piece." + i);
                        var valuePerQuantity =  document.getElementById("opt-quantity." + i);
                        if(valuePerPiece && valuePerQuantity!=null){
                            sumMultipliedValue = sumMultipliedValue+ valuePerPiece.value*valuePerQuantity.value;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
                sumMultipliedValue =sumMultipliedValue+multipliedValue;
                document.getElementById("opt-sum." + id).value = multipliedValue;
                sumValue.value=sumMultipliedValue;
                

            }

            document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
            
                var addOffPosition = document.getElementById("addingEntry");
                addOffPosition.onclick = function () {
                    val = count++;
                    console.log("count after incrementing", val);
                    appendUserRow(val)
                   
                }
                
            })




        </script>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: On delete, just iterate over all of the rows and re-set their classes.

Comment: classes? I want their IDs reduced by factor of 1

Comment: Eh yea, I meant ids. Just set them again.

Comment: Hey could you please provide syntax for one element? Is changing the opt-row sufficient for changing ID of all elements within it? Kinda struggling with JS

Comment: Look up this: _"Iterate over children of HTML element"_ and _"change html element id"_. That should get you there.